# Helidon MP 2.5, Hibernate Session createQuery() error: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, helidon

I am trying to connect to Oracle database in Helidon MP 2.5 and execute a basic findAll() query for finding all entities. I am using Hibernate as the JPA provider. I have a generic abstract CRUD repository that contains the findAll() method:

```
1. public abstract class CrudRepository<T, ID> implements CrudInterface<T, ID> {
2. 
3.     protected final Class<T> persistentClass;
4.     private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
5.     private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CrudRepository.class.getName());
6. 
7.     protected CrudRepository(Class<T> persistenceClass, HelidonPersistenceUnitInfo hpuInfo) {
8.         this.persistentClass = persistenceClass;
9.         this.sessionFactory = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration()
10.                 .addProperties(hpuInfo.getProperties())
11.                 .addAnnotatedClass(persistenceClass)
12.                 .buildSessionFactory();
13.     }
14. 
15.     public Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageableObj) {
16.         List<T> list;
17.         int page = pageableObj.getPageNum();
18.         int size = pageableObj.getMaxRows();
19. 
20.         if(page < 0 || size < 0) {
21.             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid values for page and size");
22.         }
23. 
24.         StringBuilder queryStr = new StringBuilder("SELECT e FROM " + persistentClass.getSimpleName() + " e");
25. 
26.         log.info("SQL QUERY IS: " + queryStr.toString());
27. 
28.         try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
29.             Query<T> query = session.createQuery(queryStr.toString(), persistentClass);
30.             query.setFirstResult(page * size);
31.             query.setMaxResults(size);
32.             list = query.getResultList();
33.             return new Page<T>(list, pageableObj);
34.         } catch (Exception e) {
35.             throw new RuntimeException("Failed to find entities", e);
36.         }
37. 
38.     }
39.   
40.   }
```

I have a class EmployeeRepository which extends the above CRUD repository. When I execute a test on the findAll() method:

```
1.     @Test
2.     void getEmployees() throws Exception {
3.         EmployeeRepository empRepo = new EmployeeRepository();
4.         Page<Employee> p = empRepo.findAll(new Pageable(0, 20));
5.         assertEquals(p.getEntities().size(), 20);
6.     }
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find entities

    at oal.oracle.apps.ic.helidonmstemplate.CRUD.CrudRepository.findAll(CrudRepository.java:122)
    at oal.oracle.apps.ic.helidonmstemplate.application.Employee.EmployeeControllerTest.getEmployees(EmployeeControllerTest.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
oal.oracle.apps.ic.helidonmstemplate.CRUD.CrudRepository.findAll(CrudRepository.java:119)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2170)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1190)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 22, Sql = SELECT e FROM EMPLOYEE e limit :1 , OriginalSql = SELECT e FROM EMPLOYEE e limit ?, Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513)
    ... 110 more
```

The SQL statement I created in line 24 CrudRepository appears to be correct. I tried to diagnose the issue by adding a semicolon after the statement to end it, but that did not fix the issue. I tried using query.createSQLQuery() instead of createQuery() as well. Any idea what might be causing the issue?

Comment: ORA-00933 suggest that`LIMIT 1` [is suspicious](https://dbfiddle.uk/FNt8WF4J).

Comment: Is the issue with my query string in line 24 or some other sql-dialect configuration? Also where is the 'limit' clause coming from?

Comment: Error log shows query: `SELECT e FROM EMPLOYEE e limit :1`. This query won't work in Oracle, because it has not `LIMIT` clause, as you can see in my fiddle. I don't know Hibernate, so I have not idea where it comes from.

Comment: Issue resolved, I changed my hibernate language dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect